# Is it true that for any two integers with the same least prime factor, there must be an integer with a higher lpf between them?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm sure something like this has been asked, but I can't seem to find it.

Let $a,b$ be two natural numbers such that $a<b$ and $\text{lpf}(a)=\text{lpf}(b)$. Is there always an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $a<n<b$ and $\text{lpf}(n)>\text{lpf}(a)$?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A020639

Comment: Note a fairly closed related question is [In a given sequence of consecutive integers, finding the count of integers with a least prime factor greater than $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621360/in-a-given-sequence-of-consecutive-integers-finding-the-count-of-integers-with?rq=1).

Comment: @Trev I wrote & ran a C++ program which tested all integers up to $8 \times 10^{8}$ and didn't find any exceptions, i.e., there's always an $n$ where it's lpf is larger between any $2$ consecutive integers with the same lpf.

Comment: @Trev A very closely related question is MO's [Least Prime Factor in a sequence of 2n consecutive integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68351/least-prime-factor-in-a-sequence-of-2n-consecutive-integers). The comments indicate using [A058989](http://oeis.org/A058989), which points to the associated [A049300](http://oeis.org/A049300). What these $2$ show is the least prime $p$ where at least $2p$ consecutive integers have a lpf $\le p$ is $43$, for $89$ values, starting at $14,478,292,443,584$. As this is more than $1.4\times 10^{13}$, it shows counter-examples, if any, are very large.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks! It also seems to hold for arithmetical progressions, but seems to be untrue for quadratic functions. I tried it on $f(x)=x^2+k$ for small $k$, and there are generally small counterexamples. Weirdly, $x^2+1$ has a counterexample at $x=846$ and that's the highest you see until $x^2+138$, and more surprisingly, $x^2-2$ has its first at $x=116279$, with nothing else nearby remotely as high.

Comment: For the record, after $k=-2$, the smallest $k$ in each direction with a larger smallest counterexample is $k=23662$ at $x=142117$ and $k=-20363$ at $x=130464$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer expands on my comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382281/177778) as I was asked to.

A smaller counterexample is the interval $[a,a+142],$ $a=7310131732015251470110369$.

Suppose $\operatorname{lpf}(a)=\operatorname{lpf}(b)=p$ and no such $n$ as in the original post exists. Then $a-b \ge 2p$ as $p \not = 2$ and so both $a,b$ are odd. Thus if $p$ is the $k$th prime and $h(k)$ is the Jacobsthal function applied to the product of the first $k$ primes, $$h(k-1) \ge 2p.$$
Going off the table for $h(k)$ at [OEIS A048670](https://oeis.org/A048670), we have $k \ge 20$ and so $p \ge 71$.

Given this, I decided to look for a counterexample $a,b$ with $a-b = 2 \cdot 71$, and $a \equiv 0 \pmod{71}.$ It should be noted that in fact $h(19) \ge 2 \cdot 73$, so there are probably similarly sized examples with $p=73$ instead. Examples using intervals longer than $h(19)$ are likely to be larger than the one in this post, but I haven't proved that none are smaller.

I wrote a short script to choose congruences for $a$ to satisfy modulo each prime less than $71$ such that every $n$ with $a < n < b$ is divisible by some such prime. It found many such systems of congruences, the one giving the answer in the post is given by \begin{align*} a&\equiv{1} \pmod{2}\\
a&\equiv{1} \pmod{3}\\
a&\equiv{4} \pmod{5}\\
a&\equiv{2} \pmod{7}\\
a&\equiv{7} \pmod{11}\\
a&\equiv{5} \pmod{13}\\
a&\equiv{4} \pmod{17}\\
a&\equiv{5} \pmod{19}\\
a&\equiv{4} \pmod{23}\\
a&\equiv{15} \pmod{29}\\
a&\equiv{4} \pmod{31}\\
a&\equiv{27} \pmod{37}\\
a&\equiv{23} \pmod{41}\\
a&\equiv{21} \pmod{43}\\
a&\equiv{23} \pmod{47}\\
a&\equiv{12} \pmod{53}\\
a&\equiv{16} \pmod{59}\\
a&\equiv{44} \pmod{61}\\
a&\equiv{39} \pmod{67}\\
a&\equiv{0} \pmod{71}
\end{align*}
I then combined these in the standard way to give the example. Note that I had to enforce that $a$ is not $0$ or $-2 \cdot 71$ modulo any primes less than $71$, so that indeed $\operatorname{lpf}(a) = \operatorname{lpf}(a + 2 \cdot 71) = 71$.
It is likely that slightly smaller examples exist even with $p=71$, this was just the smallest my laptop found in a short run.

Answer (score 15):

I am kind of astonished, but I've eventually discovered this to be **false**. There is a counterexample in the interval $[a,a+262],$ $a = 724968762211953720363081773921156853174119094876349$, which both have lpf of $131$, with intervening values all lower.

Comment: I assume this was found by a modified version of brute force. What optimizations did you use make the program run fast enough?

Comment: Not really, these numbers are far far too big for any kind of brute force of the type needed. IIRC I found these numbers in a list in a recent paper on computing the Jacobsthal function, cross checked their numbers against my conjecture, and found this one broke it.

Comment: Which paper was it?

Comment: I'm not sure now, but from my Google activity history, probably Hagedorn's [Computation of Jacobsthal's function h(n) for n<50](https://www.ams.org/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02166-2/S0025-5718-08-02166-2.pdf). See also https://oeis.org/A048670.

Comment: How did you get those specific numbers? Those two numbers don't appear in the paper?

Comment: You can calculate the numbers from the coverings somehow, but again, I don't remember the details. If you're just interested in the numbers, Robert Gerbicz supplies a table in the OEIS link provided which contains them all; my counterexample range corresponds to $n=32$ on that list.